# How can I make update or upgrade option for laravel script?

Tags: laravel

I have seen many websites which has upgrade version or update project button in the top. Kindly tell me how can I make this in laravel?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Comment: This is usually happening because the front-end javascript has a new version of it.  You could theoretically have a polling system in your front end code that checked the back end for a new version number or etag or something like that, and then prompt for the refresh.